# For proving Euclidean domain, how to decide the mapping?

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-domain

Whenever I get questions to prove it an "Euclidean domain(modern algebra)", I get confused in selecting the mapping.
Is there any way to choose the mapping?
Eg. If the question is to prove

> The ring  Z  of integers  is a  Euclidean domain.

In textbooks, for the above ques $d(a)=|a|$,
How to choose in general?

Comment: Which mapping? The Euclidean function?

Comment: Yes the mapping, d(a)<=d(b). How to decide on d()

Comment: This depends on the ring . There's no universal way.

Comment: Your question has so little content to it, that I think it will be pretty much impossible to answer. Please include enough relevant context, including mathematical details, definitions, etc., so that the question can be understood. Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) to see these suggestions written out explicitly.

Comment: As @Bernard said, there is no general method. You have to actually work to find one if it exists, or try to prove that it cannot (which can be tricky, especially if your ring is principal).